# Problema com if em Java

Tags: java, if

Estou tentando fazer um programa tipo "loteria", tranquei em um erro ali no `if`. Se puderem me ajudar, segue o código:

```
package praticando;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JogoNumeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Random aleatorio = new Random();
       int valor = aleatorio.nextInt(10) + 1;
       Scanner N = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Faça sua aposta digitando um número de 1 até 10: ");
        int aposta = N.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Número sorteado|---> " + valor);

        if  N = valor {
            System.out.print(" $$$$ PARABÉNS, você ganhou na loteria!!! $$$$$");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Não foi desta vez, continue apostando!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, Thiago, você está utilizando o operador errado. Para Atribuição utilizamos o igual (=), para comparação utilizamos (==), tenta ai vê se é isso. Logo na linha if  N = valor tenta if  N == valor ;

Comment: Dê uma olhada sobre [como fazer perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Olá Marcus Ítalo, você tem razão. Modifiquei mas ainda não rodou.

Comment: @MarcusItalo `N` é um `Scanner`, não faz sentido compará-lo com um `int`. O que deve ser feito é `if (valor == aposta)`

Comment: Modifiquei, mas ainda não ta rodando.

Comment: Sim, funcionou. Obrigado. *

Comment: Mas a com uma lampada amarela com exclamação. Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você comparar com a variável `aposta`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    int valor = aleatorio.nextInt(10) + 1;
    Scanner N = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Faça sua aposta digitando um número de 1 até 10: ");
    int aposta = N.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Número sorteado|---> " + valor);
    if (aposta == valor) {
        System.out.print(" $$$$ PARABÉNS, você ganhou na loteria!!! $$$$$");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Não foi desta vez, continue apostando!");
    }
}
```